# abas-ERP (FO- Language): Getting Weekday of abas date

Tags: erp, abas

Is there any FO function for getting the weekday of an abas date as short. e.g.:
Today: 07.04.2016 -> Thursday (th) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In example, when you have;

```
.type GD xddate                 ? _F|defined(U|xddate)
.type int xidate               ? _F|defined(U|xidate)
..
!START
.formula U|xddate = "."
.formula U|xidate = U|xddate//7
.println 'F|tostring(U|xidate)'
```

The variable U|xtdate will continue "4" which is the fourth day of the week, Thursday.

Comment: .formula U|xtdate = U|xddate//7 returns an integer! So better declare it also as int :-)

Comment: Absolutely agree ;) changed it

Answer (score 0):

Another deeper approach would be, to get the name of the weekday from the built-in dictionary.

See in HOMEDIR/msg.cc.dic which number monday has (in my case 420)
Then this FO-line

```
.type text xtweekday
.type GD xddate
.formula U|xddate = "09.04.2016"
.atext -language E xtweekday 'F|eval(420 + U|xddate//7)'
```

> 'xtweekday' returns Saturday

for "today" just write

```
.atext -language E xtweekday 'F|eval(420 + G|date//7)'
```

You can also use the more powerfull **.translate** command, but this is in this case not really necessary.